# Java Validation Better way to use hashcodes

Tags: javascript, java, spring, validation, hashcode

I am trying to validate user input using a custom validator, Below is the validator code I have been using.

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    System.out.println("Validating...");
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "email", "email.required");
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "password.required"); 
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "address", "address.required");
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "age", "age.required");
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "full_name", "full_name.required");
}
```

And then I've been sending this to my controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/newUser")
    public String newResults(@Valid Volunteer vol, BindingResult result, Model model) {
            if(result.hasErrors()) {
                model.addAttribute("errors", result.getAllErrors().get(0).hashCode());
                return "/sign_up";
            }
            else {
              //other code
```

I've then been getting codes like 545324234 on my HTML page. Which I've then been using JavaScript to ask if it is a certain number then to tell the page it is this error code.

```
function check(){
var x = document.getElementById("error2").textContent;
if (x=="1182092568"){
    document.getElementById("error").textContent="An Email is required to sign up!";
}
```

And then how I am displaying the error code to check

```
<p id="error2">${errors}</p>
```

I was just wondering if there was a better/more efficient way to accomplish this. As this works for the solution I am trying to achieve but I can't help but think there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Well, you could store a function using the key in some object/map, try to retrieve that function and if you got it you call it. But why aren't you returing the error message or a structured error object instead?

Comment: Cheers, I didn't think of that. Thank you